# How to stop service automatically in Android

Tags: android, android-service

i have used two services in single Activity in Android and start the services when my activity is start. I'm trying to downloading some images in onStartCommand() in Both services. But right now i want to stop the services automatically or stop it self after onStartCommand() finished his work.How do I stop service it self after finishing the onStartCommand().Thanks !!

This start service in onCreate() in Activity

```
Intent intent_Service = new Intent(CustomActionActivity.this , DownLodProfileSrvice.class);
        startService(intent_Service);

        Intent intent = new Intent(CustomActionActivity.this, MyService.class);
        startService(intent);
```

Here is my service code

```
public class DownLodProfileSrvice extends Service
        {
protected SQLiteDatabase db;
public Runnable mRunnable=null;
        MyDbHelper myDBHelper;
        String namespace="http://103.24.4.60/xxxxx/xxxxx.svc";
        File newFolder;

        public ImageLoader imageLoader;
        DisplayImageOptions options;
        String str_Authentication_Token,result;
            public DownLodProfileSrvice(){

        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent){
        // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not yet implemented");
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        Log.e("TAG","ScreenListenerService---OnCreate ");

        myDBHelper=new MyDbHelper(this);
        myDBHelper.onOpen(db);
       }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent,int flags,int startId){
        final Handler mHandler=new Handler();
        mRunnable=new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run()
        {
        new LoadProfilePic().execute();

        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable,10*1000);
        }
        };
        mHandler.postDelayed(mRunnable, 10 *1000);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
        }

    private class LoadProfilePic extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        LoadProfilePics();
        return null;
    }

}

            public void LoadProfilePics() {
                db = myDBHelper.getWritableDatabase();

                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from ALL_Post ", null);
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                String strProfile_Pics = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("ProfilePICURL"));
                String strDownLoadStatus = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("DownLoad_Status"));
                if(strDownLoadStatus.equals("0"))
                {
                    String URL_downLoadProfilePic = namespace + "/DownloadFile/FilePathMobile/PROFILEPICPATH/FileName/" + strProfile_Pics;
                    newFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + File.separator + "classNKK_ProfilePic");
                    download_PngFileImgLoader(URL_downLoadProfilePic, newFolder, strProfile_Pics);
                    db.execSQL("update ALL_Post set DownLoad_Status='1' where ProfilePICURL ='" + strProfile_Pics + "'");
                    Log.e("URL_downLoadProfilePic ", " ==========>" + URL_downLoadProfilePic);

                }

            } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
        cursor.close();
            }

}
```

Comment: I would set a sharedpreferences boolean and check value with timed task. Then if true/false (depending on what you want) stop service and stop task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The service can call stopSelf() when it is done. If you use IntentService, this will happen automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need a service for downloading a file!
Services are a tool for performing long running tasks which is not your case. The best practice for downloading a file is to just use an `AsyncTask`.

Move `LoadProfilePics` to your activity and execute it just once.
Also you can check the result of `doInBackground` of the AsyncTask in `onPostExecution`.

See [this](https://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/) link for more information on `AsyncTask`